# Сформировать SQL запрос к двум таблицам

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

```
searchjur (id, name_event)
conditions (id_event, `id_jur, status_select_jur)
```

В них следующие поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо создать запрос для вывода всех полей таблицы `searchjur`, присоединив значение из таблицы `conditions` поля `status_select_jur` , если они есть и соответствуют `id_jur` который будет известен до форматирования запроса в переменной.

Цель: Если `id_jur = 58`, результат должен быть такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если `id_jur = 59`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте тег используемой СУБД (mysql, postgres, etc)

Comment: Я удалил из вопроса ваше замечание, что код будет добавлен в комментарий. Добавте вашу попытку сформировать запрос прямо в вопрос. Ничего страшного, если он  "безполезен", как вы выразились.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для MySQL/MariaDB

```
SELECT s.*, COALESCE(c.status_select_jur, 0) 
FROM searchjur s
LEFT JOIN conditions c ON s.id=c.id_event
AND c.id_jur=58 ORDER BY s.id;
```

Comment: В значение c.id_jur просто подставте соответсвтующую переменную

Comment: не показывает поле status_select_jur (

Comment: Вообще надо бы конечно уточнить у топикстартера, что у него за SQL, а потом уже отвечать, но у вас в решении в общем-то SQL-92 (ANSI-92) так что взлететь должно практически везде.